# turn off sharepoint email overnight

Tags: email, sharepoint, office365

Is it possible, and if so how, to automatically 'turn off' sharepoint Office 365 email overnight for a business.  We are looking into improving worklife balance in our company and one of the initiatives is to look into shutting down email overnight so managers and staff don't access or read their emails outside of business hours.  For example at 6pm all emails get stored on the server but not sent until 7.30am the next morning?

Answer (score 0):

emails in SharePoint are sent through timer jobs. Enabling and disabling them at specific hours is possible through a task schedule on your server. 
Use the following powershell: Enable-SPTimerJob and Disable-SPTimerJob : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906546.aspx

All timer jobs can be seen through central administration > Monitoring > Timer Jobs. In your question it is unclear which timer jobs you want to disable/enable.

EDIT: it seems you don't need the task schedule as you can edit the schedules of the jobs also with powershell:
https://www.petri.com/manage-timer-jobs-sharepoint-2013-with-powershell

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at this.  What we want to happen is that after 6pm all email that goes through our sharepoint gets stopped from being sent until the following morning at 7.30am.  This way we can make sure that staff don't feel the pressure to keep checking their email when away from work.